# Give Permission To A User Using Workflow From One Site To Another

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow, permissions

I have two sites say S1 and S2. On the S1 I have a workflow which checks particular condition in a list and performs an action (provides permission to a users on S1).

Somehow, I need to check the condition on S1, but give the permission to users on S2. Could you please help me to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.